# Positioning of label when convert Lyx equation to TeX code

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

When Lyx equations converted to TeX, the automatically generated code is

```
\begin{equation}
(content of equation) \label{...}
\end{equation}.
```

If I want to automatically convert Lyx equations by TeX equations with the form

```
\begin{equation}\label{...}
(content of equation) 
\end{equation},
```

How can I do? the difference is the position of '\label' in code.

Comment: Welcome. // Why does the label hurt you? You could just ignore it, i.e. don't reference to it.

Comment: I cannot see any reason to move the `\label{…}`. AFAIK, already the `Formula` in the `lyx` files have the `\label` at the end. Can you explain, why you want it at the beginning? If I would really need it, I would write a perl script to post-process the generated file. But IMHO this does not really make sense.

Comment: I also know this is not crucial, but my coworkers want to put \label at the first. How can I approach this problem by perl?